# dynamically allocate memory for array of strings

Tags: c

I have an array of strings `char allWords[300][30]` and I noticed the size of the array is too large for the problem I am solving.How would I dynamically allocate memory for the size of the array as this is not known at compile time.

Comment: Use `malloc()` & `realloc()` calls to allocate memory & `free()` when that memory is no longer needed. Plenty of resources online. Comeback when you've problems with your code.

Answer (score 0):

First declare a character pointer to hold your array.

`char *allWords;`

If all the items have the same size, then with each new item the memory allocated should grow statically, in your case it seems to be 30 bytes.

Now let's say we to need allocate memory for 2 items.

```
#define STRING_SIZE 30
allWords = malloc(3 * STRING_SIZE);
```

In this case we allocate 90 bytes of memory, that can hold three strings in it.

If more strings i.e. items 'arrive', we need to resize our array, to hold more items, for which we are going to use `realloc()`.

Imagine if have 5 more items to add into array.

```
allWords = realloc(allWords, (5 + 3) * STRING_SIZE);
```

Then do not forget to `free()` the memory.

```
free(allWords);
```

Edit 1.
If the length of your strings are different, then instead holding a characater array, hold a `char **` i.e. an array of character pointers.